# Computing a 3D rotation matrix aligning 1 orthonormal basis to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have 2 sets of 3 vectors ($\vec{u_1}$, $\vec{v_1}$, $\vec{w_1}$, $\vec{u_2}$, $\vec{v_2}$, $\vec{w_2}$) and the 3 vectors form an orthonormal basis. That is:

$$
|\vec{u}|=|\vec{v}|=|\vec{w}|=1 \\
\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}=0 \\
\vec{u} \times \vec{v}= \vec{w}
$$

Using the values for the vectors, how do I compute the 3D rotation matrix $R$ that rotates the first orthonormal basis onto the other? That is, $R \vec{u_1} = \vec{u_2}$, $R \vec{v_1} = \vec{v_2}$, etc.

Comment: If $R_1$ rotates $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$ to $\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{u}_3$ and similarly with $R_2$, then $R_2R_1^{-1}$ does the job. You do know how to find $R_1,R_2$, right? The inverse of an orthogonal matrix is its transpose. Alternatively you can calculate inner products to get the coordinates of one orthonormal basis w.r.t. another, and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define the (orthogonal) matrices :

$$B_1=[u_1|v_1|w_1],\ \ \  B_2=[u_2|v_2|w_2]$$

where $v$ stands for the column vector with entries the coordinates of $\vec{v}$.

Their columns being issued from ortho**normal** direct bases, these matrices are ortho**gonal** with a determinant $1$.

You want a matrix $R$ such that

$$Ru_1=u_2, \ \ Rv_1=v_2, \ \ Rw_1=w_2$$

These 3 equations can be gathered into a single matrix equation

$$R[u_1|v_1|w_1]=[u_2|v_2|w_2] \ \ \iff \ \ RB_1=B_2\tag{1}$$

Conclusion : right multiplying (1) by $B_1^{-1}$, we arrive at the conclusion that :

$$R=B_2B_1^{-1}=B_2B_1^T\tag{2}$$

(the last expression being due to the fact that $B_1$ is an orthogonal matrix.)

Remark :

a) (2) gives in particular $\det(R)=\det(B_2)\det(B_1)=1$ : $R$ is indeed a rotation.

b) expression (2) says that we can compute matrix $R$, as remarked by @Jyrki Lahtonen, as the matrix of mutual dot products of the old base with respect to thenew one (it was usual, now less common, to designate these numbers as the "direction cosines" of the transformation (see for example [here](http://www.starlino.com/dcm_tutorial.html)).